# Why the present progressive tense is used in "you are coming from"

Tags: meaning, present-tense, progressive-aspect

In a brand's advertising commentary, there is “You don’t have to say a word to let them know where you are coming from”. I am wondering why the present progressive tense is used in "you are coming from".

Answer (score 4):

To know or see where somebody is "coming from" is an idiomatic phrase which means to understand someone's intention, motive, or point of view. The present progressive makes sense in this context because it is a continuous action (the motive for someone's action does not have a definite beginning or ending but is instead a sort of background process driving their actions which is not yet completed).